# Zooming problem in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using `UIScrollView`.In that scrollview I placing `UIImageViews` in serial order.Zooming is not working .This is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];

    NSArray *imageArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test1.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"test2.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"test3.png"], nil];

    scrollView_=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width+20, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [scrollView_ setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
scrollView_.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
scrollView_.clipsToBounds = NO;
scrollView_.scrollEnabled = YES;
scrollView_.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scrollView_.delegate=self;
    scrollView_.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=NO;
    scrollView_.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=NO;
    scrollView_.contentSize = CGSizeMake([imageArray count]*self.scrollView_.frame.size.width, self.scrollView_.frame.size.height); 

    [scrollView_ setMaximumZoomScale:3.0];
    [scrollView_ setMinimumZoomScale:1];
    [scrollView_ setZoomScale:1];
    [scrollView_ setBouncesZoom:YES];
    [scrollView_ setBounces:YES];

    for(int i=0;i<[imageArray count];i++)
    {
        UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[imageArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        imageView.frame=CGRectMake((i*320)+(i*20), 0, 320, 480);
        [imageView_ setTag:i];
        [scrollView_ addSubview:imageView];

       [imageView release];
   }

   [self.view addSubview:scrollView_];


}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
   return [scrollView_ viewWithTag:page_];


}



- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)_scrollView
{


    CGFloat pageWidth = _scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((_scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    self.page_=page;



}
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Where have you set -

```
[self.mainScroll setZoomScale:(float)];
```

I guess by default this is 1. So no zoom happens...

Answer (score 0):

Create a container view, and add imageViews into the container view,
then use the container view as zoomview.

```
- viewDidLoad {

   // ---
   self.containerView =[[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];

   self.containerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [imageArray count]*self.scrollView_.frame.size.width, self.scrollView_.frame.size.height);
  [scrollView_ addSubView:self.containerView];

   for(int i=0;i<[imageArray count];i++)
    {
        UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[imageArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        imageView.frame=CGRectMake((i*320)+(i*20), 0, 320, 480);
        [imageView_ setTag:i];
        [self.containerView addSubview:imageView];

       [imageView release];
   }


 // --
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
   return self.containerView;


}
```